# Creating temporary directories with suffixes

Tags: c++, linux, temporary-directory

I'd like to create a temporary of the form `/tmp/prefix.XXXXXX.suffix`, however the only function I know of to create temporary directories is `mkdtemp` which requires the `XXXXXX` characters to appear at the end of the template. Is there another way to create a temporary directory that allows this?

Comment: Worst comes to worst, you can always rename the created directories to include the suffix in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir /tmp/prefix.`date +%s`.suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

This script basically creates a random six character string and uses that to make a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
characters=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B  C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z );
charactersLength=${#characters[@]};
randomString="";
for i in `seq 6`;
do
    randomNumber=$(( $RANDOM % $charactersLength ));
    randomString=$randomString${characters[randomNumber]};
done
mkdir "/tmp/prefix."$randomString".suffix";
```